# Python: BaseHTTPServer global var?

Tags: python, basehttpserver

I'm new to python and wondering if it is possible using BaseHTTPServer to store a global var that is accessible to all requests? Basically I have an async process that requires a POST back into the server as a separate request from the original request, that I would like to write back through to the original request, via a token I'd generate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

To maintain state, you'll need a web framework that supports global variables across requests, or some kind of session management.

[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is super easy to get up and running and has sessions available.

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    flask.session['post_token'] = MakeToken()
    return '...Content...'

@app.route('/poster', methods=['POST'])
def poster():
    if flask.session['post_token']:
        DO STUFF HERE


# set the secret key.  keep this really secret:
app.secret_key = 'A0Zr98j/3yX R~XHH!jxxxRT'
```